# Mobile screen reader issue for react based applications

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility, voiceover

I am working on react based application for mobile screen readers. Use case is that for a dialog with menu items, I have to keep one button to dismiss the dialog, which will be on top of the dialog. I have to set it's tabIndex to 0 to make it accessible, which results in dismiss button being the first focusable item.

Expectation is that after screen reader lands focus on first menu item, the dismiss button should be accessible. How to approach this problem?

I have tried the following:

```
<Dialog open={this.state.menuOpen} className="hide-default-dialog-container"
        content={<div className="actionsheet-view-bg" onClick={() => {
            this.setState({menuOpen: !this.state.menuOpen})
        }}> {this.getDismissButtonForActionSheet()}
            <div className="actionsheet-view-container"> {this.getActionSheetItems()} </div>
        </div>}
/>
```

Comment: Could you add code to demonstrate the problem, this would make it easier to help?

Comment: <Dialog
                    open={this.state.menuOpen}
                    className="hide-default-dialog-container"
                    content={
                        <div className="actionsheet-view-bg" onClick={() => { this.setState({ menuOpen: !this.state.menuOpen }) }}>
                            {this.getDismissButtonForActionSheet()}
                            <div className="actionsheet-view-container">
                                {this.getActionSheetItems()}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                />

Comment: @MaartenDev I have added the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You have four options here:-

### Option 1. Move the close button to the end of the dialog next to any save / update buttons.

The 'x' in the top right of dialog boxes is expected, but there is no reason why you can't add a close button at the bottom of your dialog instead, placed after any save / update buttons.

So in the footer of your dialog have

```
<button>Save</button> <button>Cancel</button>
```

You could still maintain the 'x' in the top right but use `aria-hidden="true"` on it without a `tabindex`.

### Option 2. Change the button to be after the content in the DOM but use absolute positioning to place it visually

You could move the close button after the content (in the DOM) and then use CSS to position it in the top right of the dialog.

This is a bit of a grey area on whether it would constitute a `logical tab order` but I think it is still accessible enough to be a good pass.

### Option 3. Manage the focus programatically.

When the dialog opens you could just programatically focus the first item. Just make sure you trap focus within your dialog so the close button can be reached.

### Option 4. Do nothing

**This is the best option**

There is nothing wrong with the close button being the first focusable item (in fact it may be preferential to allow users who accidentally open the dialog to close it quickly).

Screen reader users are used to exploring dialogs and so it won't impact them if the first focusable item is the close button. It may even be reassuring to know that you have provided an accessible close button (as many developers forget about keyboard users and make buttons inaccessible to close dialogs).

### Semantics, Escape and Focus Management.

To further increase the accessibility change your close `div` into a `button` as that way you don't have to worry about adding `tabindex` as it is semantically correct. (I have assumed the close button is a div as you said you added a `tabindex="0"` - if it is already a button then the `tabindex` is not needed)

Secondly make sure the dialog can be closed using the `Escape` key as that is expected behaviour.

Finally ensure focus remains confined to the modal (not just via the `tab` key, you need to add `aria-hidden="true"` to all the content outside of the dialog while it is open as screen reader users navigate with more than just the `tab` key, in fact it is a secondary way of navigating, screen reader users navigate by headings 1-6, links, forms, buttons etc.).

This may require structuring your page to make it easier

For example:-

```
<header aria-hidden="false"></header>
<main aria-hidden="false"></main>
<footer aria-hidden="false"></footer>
<dialog aria-hidden="true"></dialog>
```

would turn into the following when the dialog is open (and reverted when the dialog is closed).

```
<header aria-hidden="true"></header>
<main aria-hidden="true"></main>
<footer aria-hidden="true"></footer>
<dialog aria-hidden="false"></dialog>
```

Comment: If i set aria-hidden={true} without tabindex for the hidden dismiss button, it won't be accessible by screen reader.

Comment: Yes but the second button at the bottom I said to add will be.

Comment: i need button at the top. As all the dialogs now a days have dismiss button exposed to screen readers at the top.

Comment: Then use option 2, 3 or better yet do nothing as per option 4, it is why I gave you some choices. There is nothing wrong with the close button being the first item to have focus.

Comment: I have edited my answer to indicate that they are different options, you need only do one (and the last section 'Semantics, Escape and Focus Management.'). Hopefully that clears it up for you.

Comment: managing screen reader focus programaticaly is difficult. how will i land focus on first menu item. there is no dialog life-cycle method to do so. i have a bug filed for the same so doing nothing is not an option.

Comment: How do you open the dialog? Surely you have a button press that you can hook into and set the focus after opening the dialog?

Comment: can you describe more on last comment you have mentioned?

Comment: Whatever button you use to open your dialog, within the function for that button (where you set the dialog state to make it open) you could also just add a method which focuses the first item after you change the state. you can use `.focus()` in react the same as vanilla JS

Comment: now that you have this sorted care to accept my answer bud?